# $\min(\det(\mathbf{A}))$ for special matrix $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: matrices, st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, determinants

(The construction of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is not difficult to be understood. You can first jump to **A Toy Example** to take a glance. Any idea or suggestion would be appealing for me.)

---

**The Original Problem:**

Given $N,D\in\mathbb{Z}^+~(D\ge N)$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the vector $\mathbf{p}$ and the matrix $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are defined as follows:

- $\mathbf{p}=[p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_N]$, where $p_i$s are selected from $\{1,2,\cdots,D\}$ and satisfying the condition of $(p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_N)$.
- Given $\mathbf{p}$, there is $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}=[a_{ij}]_{N\times N}$, where $a_{ij}=e^{-\alpha |p_i-p_j|}$.

I am trying to find out the property of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$. Based some of my findings, I am confused by the following two subproblems:

$(\text{Q}1)$ Can we conveniently calculate the value of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})=f(\mathbf{p})$ for a given $\mathbf{p}$? In other words, is there a way to explicitly unfold $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$?

$(\text{Q}2)$ Is $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ positive semi-definite?

$(\text{Q}3)$ Does $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$ hit its minimal value only when $(p_{i+1}-p_i=1)$? By the way, in this case, $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ will become a special symmetric Toeplitz matrix.

---

**A Toy Example:**

Given $N=3$, $D=10$ and $\alpha =1$. I construct $\mathbf{p}_1=[3,4,5]$ and $\mathbf{p}_2=[2,5,7]$. Then we have:

$$
\det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_1} \right) =\left| \begin{matrix}
    1&      e^{-1}&     e^{-2}\\
    e^{-1}&     1&      e^{-1}\\
    e^{-2}&     e^{-1}&     1\\
\end{matrix} \right|\approx 0.748,
$$

and

$$
\det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_2} \right) =\left| \begin{matrix}
    1&      e^{-3}&     e^{-5}\\
    e^{-3}&     1&      e^{-2}\\
    e^{-5}&     e^{-2}&     1\\
\end{matrix} \right|\approx 0.979 > \det \left( \mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_1} \right) .
$$

---

**Some of My Efforts:**

I may have the following observations:

$(\text{O}1)$ The diagonal elements of $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are all ones since $|p_i-p_i|=0$.

$(\text{O}2)$ All elements of $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ are in $[0,1]$.

$(\text{O}3)$ $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ is symmetric since $|p_i-p_j|=|p_j-p_i|$.

$(\text{O}4)$ Actually, the order of $\mathbf{p}_i$s do not affect the value of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$.

I guess that $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ has the following two properties:

$(\text{P}1)$ The answer of $(\text{Q}2)$ is "Yes", *i.e.*, $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ is positive semi-definite.

$(\text{P}2)$ The answer of $(\text{Q}3)$ is "Yes", *i.e.*, $\left[\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})=\min\left\{{\det(\mathbf{A}_{\mathbf{p}_k})}\right\}\right] \Leftrightarrow \left[ \forall i, ~p_{i+1}-p_{i}=1 \right]$.

The above conjectures of $(\text{P}1)$ and $(\text{P}2)$ is empirically presented. I write the following Python code to validate them and find that all randomly generated $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$ satisfy $(\text{P}1)$ and $(\text{P}2)$:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy import spatial

alpha = 1
N = 10
X = np.arange(N).reshape(N, 1)
X = np.exp(-alpha * spatial.distance.cdist(X, X))
X_det = np.linalg.det(X)
for D in range(N, 1000):
    for i in range(100):
        p = np.array(random.sample(range(1, D + 1), N)).reshape(N, 1)
        A = np.exp(-alpha * spatial.distance.cdist(p, p))
        A_det = np.linalg.det(A)
        if A_det <= 0:
            print(A_det, p.reshape(N,))  # det(A) <= 0
            exit(0)
        if A_det < X_det and abs(A_det - X_det) > 1e-8:
            print(p, p.reshape(N,))  # det(A) < det(X) with numerical tolerance
            exit(0)
print('Done.')
```

I test many combinations of $\{\alpha, N, D\}$. I see that there is no any case satisfy the conditions of `A_det <= 0` and `A_det < X_det`.

---

**Why I Try to Study $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$?**

I study the entropy of multivariate Gaussian distributions with some special covariance matrices (*i.e.*, the above defined $\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p}$). The entropy value is related to $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$ (you can see more details from my previous problems below).

I have made efforts and spent more than 14 days on it. Specifically, I read some textbooks, papers and blogs related to it. Here are some previous problems posted by me: [Problem 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524167/expectations-of-multivariate-gaussian-entropy), [Problem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526630/prove-disprove-the-matrix-convergence-in-probability), [Problem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529767/prove-disprove-mathbbe-ln-det-mathbfa-rightarrow-0-when-bounded) and [Problem 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525722/is-the-determinant-of-mathbfa-in0-1n-times-n-bounded). However, I am still stucked. Now I think that the key step is to resolve the problem I posted above.

I am sorry for occupying much public resource of this platform. But I really want to resolve the problems, especially $(\text{Q}2)$ and $(\text{Q}3)$. Could you please provide help or some tips?

Comment: This is cross posted from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530343).

Comment: Hi @prets, I was urgently finding the answer since I was confused by the problems for half a month. I first post the problem on math.SE, then I additionally posted it here. Sorry for occupying so much resource of these two platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1**  The determinant is $\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} (1 - e^{-2\alpha(p_{n+1}-p_n)})$.

**Q2**  Yes, using the answer to **Q1**.

**Q3**  Yes, using the answer to **Q1**.

---

---

The formula for **Q1** is proved by induction on $N$.
The base case $N=1$ is just $\det(1)_{1\times1} = 1$.
For $N>1$, let $c = e^{-\alpha(p_N^{\phantom.} - p_{N-1}^{\phantom.})}$,
and let ${\bf A'_p}$ be the matrix obtained from ${\bf A_p}$
by subtracting $c$ times row $N-1$ from row $N$
and then subtracting $c$ times column $N-1$ from column $N$.
Then $\det{\bf A'_p} = \det{\bf A_p}$.
But the last row and column of ${\bf A'_p}$ are all zero
except for the $(N,N)$ entry which is $1-c^2$.
Therefore $\det{\bf A'_p}$ is $1-c^2$ times the determinant of
the symmetric matrix obtained from ${\bf A_p}$ by deleting its
$N$-th row and $N$-th column -- which is just ${\bf A_{p'}}$
where ${\bf p'} = [p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{N-1}]$.
This completes the induction step and the proof.

---

**Q2** By the product formula, $\det A$ is positive, as is the determinant of
every symmetric minor of $A$ (which is of the same form as $A$ for some
subsequence of $p_1,\ldots,p_N$).

---

**Q3** This too follows from the product formula:
each factor $1 - e^{-2\alpha(p_{n+1}-p_n)}$ is at least
$1 - e^{-2\alpha}$, with equality if and only if $p_{n+1} - p_n = 1$.

---

---

We can also deduce the positive answer to **Q2** by constructing
linearly independent probability distributions $\mu_i$ on the real numbers
whose covariance matrix is proportional to ${\bf A_p}$: the distribution $\mu_i$
chooses integers $p \geq p_i$ with probability
$(1-e^{-\alpha}) e^{-\alpha(p-p_i)}$.
If the real numbers $p_i$ are not required to be integers then we can achieve
the same goal using continuous $\mu_i$ with distribution functions
$\alpha e^{-\alpha(p-p_i)}$ supported on $p \geq p_i$.

Comment: I would particularly appreciate @Noam D. Elkies for his/her efforts and providing such two long and detailed answers. I can understand this answer. It is exciting for me that we can calculate the explicit form for $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$.

Comment: I also think that the previous answer by @Noam D. Elkies is inspiring and constructive for me.

Answer (score 5):

To answer Question Q2: Yes, as the special case
$u_j = \alpha p_j$ of the following result.
We use $j,k$ for the indices rather than $i,j$
because we need $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

**Proposition.** *For pairwise distinct real numbers $u_j$
the symmetric matrix $a_{jk} = \exp \left(-\left| u_j - u_k \right|\right)$
$(1 \leq j,k \leq N)$ is positive definite.*

*Proof*: This will follow from the fact that the function $e^{-|x|}$ has
a positive Fourier transform, and thus can be written as
a positive linear combination of the functions $e^{ixy}$; namely
$$
e^{-|x|} = \frac1\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ixy} \frac{dy}{y^2+1}
$$
(a well-known application of contour integration or Fourier inversion).
Indeed for any nonzero test vector $(c_j)_{j=1}^N$ we find
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N\!\sum_{k=1}^N a_{jk} c_j c_k
= \frac1\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \left|\sum_{j=1}^N c_j e^{iu_j y}\right|^2
  \frac{dy}{y^2+1} \geq 0;
$$
and the equality is strict unless $\sum_{j=1}^N c_j e^{iu_j y} = 0$
for all $y$, which is impossible for distinct $u_j$.  **QED**

Comment: Once we know that $a_{jk} = \exp \left(-\left| u_j - u_k \right|\right)$
is positive definite for all distinct $u_j$, a positive answer to Question Q3 
soon follows via the theorem that the map $A \mapsto \log \det A$ 
is concave on the cone of positive-definite matrices.

Comment: Hi @Noam D. Elkies, thanks for providing such an answer for $(\text{Q}2)$ and a hint for $(\text{Q}3)$! However, I may understand only a little about your above comment. Specifically, why we can answer $(\text{Q}3)$ directly via the theorem? Why the mapping is concave? And what is the relationship between the concave property and the minimal value of $\det(\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{p})$? Could you please provide more details about that?

Comment: Hi @Noam D. Elkies, I am confused by how the second equation is obtained. Could your please slow down and provide some details about that?

Comment: Specifically, I do not understand why there is $|\sum \cdots|^2$? I can only get $\sum_{j=1}^N{\sum_{k=1}^N{c_jc_ke^{i\left( u_j-u_k \right) y}}}$.

Comment: Hi @Noam D. Elkies, I find that your second equation is correct. Now I may understand your current answer. However, I can still not understand your hint for $(\text{Q}3)$.

Comment: Hi @BinChen -- I'm feeling a bit silly now because my answer
turns out to be needlessly baroque:
there's a simple closed form for the determinant,
which answers Q1 and makes Q2 and Q3 elementary.
See my new answer.  I'll keep this answer up because
it proves the positivity of matrices $(a_{jk}) = (\det f(p_j-p_k))$ 
for many functions $f$ for which the determinant does not have
a simple closed form.  I can still expand on my hint for Q3,
but not before going to sleep!